# Call URL x times where x is in the JSON response after the first call

Tags: java, algorithm, parsing, json, http

I have to make an HTTP POST request by passing header and body. In the body, I need to provide a `pageNumber` before posting data so I am starting with "1" initially. After that I will post data and I will get a JSON response back as shown below.

```
{
    "response": {
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "entries": 200,
        "numberOfPages": 3
    },
    "list": [
        {
            // some stuff here
        }
    ],
    "total": 1000
}
```

Now in the above response `numberOfPages` are 3 so I need to make a total of three calls to the same URL. Since we already made 1 call I will make 2 more calls with `pageNumber` "2" and "3" in the body.

The logic is like this but problem here is that I don't know what is the value for `numberOfPages` and I get to know this value after the first call with `pageNumber` 1.

```
for(int i=1; i<=numberOfPages; i++) {
    // call getBody by passing corresponding pageNumber
    // post data with header and body

}
```

Below is my working code. I just need to call the same URL until `numberOfPages` times by just changing the body. For each call, it should be made with the corresponding `pageNumber`.

```
private void collect() {
  String endpoint = "url_endpoint";
  try {
    final URI uri = URI.create(endpoint);
    int number = 1;
    while (true) {
      HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(getBody(number), getHeader());
      ResponseEntity<Stuff> responseEntity =
          HttpClient.getInstance().getClient()
              .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Stuff.class);
      Stuff response = responseEntity.getBody();
      // do stuff with response here.
      int expectedNumber = (int) response.getPaginationResponse().getTotalPages();
      if (number == expectedNumber || expectedNumber == 0) {
        break;
      }
      number++;
    }
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}

private String getBody(final int number) {
  Input input = new Input(entries, number, 0);
  Body body = new Body("Stuff", input);
  return gson.toJson(body);
}
```

Is this the right way to do it or is there any better and efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a for loop, consider a `do {} while (pageCount <= numberOfPages)`
loop and use an increment operator inside the loop. For this to work though both pageCount and numberOfPages need to have scoping outside of the loop, ie instantiated before the `do{ }` statement.

`do{ } while ()` loops are guaranteed to run once, then perform the test in the `while ()` to check if they continue. `while( ){ }` loops perform the check, then run until a value of false is found.

```
    int number = 1;
    int expectedNumber;
    do {
      HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(getBody(number), getHeader());
      ResponseEntity<Stuff> responseEntity =
          HttpClient.getInstance().getClient()
              .exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Stuff.class);
      Stuff response = responseEntity.getBody();
      // do stuff with response here.
      expectedNumber = (int) response.getPaginationResponse().getTotalPages();
      number++;
    } while (number <= expectedNumber && expectedNumber > 0);
```

Comment: Is this better approach than what I have? Also can you provide an example on how it works just to make myself clear?